# Firestore Query Builder not working on References

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

This one has me thoroughly stumped.

I have a Firestore collection 'offersread' where I track which and when offers are viewed by users. The table is simple (see first screenshot) with two references ('offers' and 'users') and a timestamp. I want to query 'offersread' to see if an offer has been read or not. The final query will search on both 'offerRef' and 'userRef' but I can't even get a single condition on 'offerRef' to work.

I have copy/pasted the reference as it is displayed in the results (see second image), I have removed the first forward slash, and still no results are returned. I partly expected an index needed to be created, but Query Builder doesn't call for that automatically like it normally does.

What am I missing? TIA

[Collection settings - the value is stored as a reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yauS.png)

[Query builder - the values are shown below correctly as references](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPre9.png)

[But when I try to search on that reference, nothing is returned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXe1U.png)

I have copy/pasted the reference as it is displayed in the results (see second image), I have removed the first forward slash, and still no results are returned. I partly expected an index needed to be created, but Query Builder doesn't call for that automatically like it normally does.

I've read solutions here that state Query Builder doesn't support reference lookups, but even when I use the following JS code, nothing is returned:

```
    const db = new Firestore({ projectId: projectId.trim() });
    const offersReadSnapshot = await db.collection('offersread').where('userRef', '==', '/users/Ja6VILgvb3N1b4KTL0Pmthlwcrr2').get();
```

What am I missing? TIA

[Collection settings - the value is stored as a reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yauS.png)
[Query builder - the values are shown below correctly as references](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPre9.png)
[But when I try to search on that reference, nothing is returned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXe1U.png)

Comment: It's not possible.  Note that your query is using type "string", which is not the same as reference.  Reference just isn't an option today in the console.  However, you should be able to use a reference value as a filter in your app code.

Comment: Thanks, @DougStevenson. I've tried everything I know to do in the code. I pass in the ID value as a string and then convert it to the document reference, but this isn't working either. Any thoughts are appreciated:
````const userDocRef = db.collection('users').doc(userRef);

// Fetch all read offer IDs for the user
const offersReadSnapshot = await db.collection('offersread').where('userRef', '==', userDocRef).get();````

Comment: Resolved - Always check your field names. :-)